# Argument Valid or Not

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, problem-solving

Premise $1$ : $\neg p \wedge q$

Premise $2$ : $\neg p \implies \neg r$

Premise $3$ : $\neg r \implies s$

Premise $4$ : $s \implies t$

Conclusion : $t$

How to check this argument is valid or not?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Truth table ? Natural Deduction ?

Comment: [Tree Proof](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((¬p∧q)∧(¬p→¬r)∧(¬r→s)∧(s→t))→t).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Rules of Inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the premisses written in argument form as follows.

$$\begin{align}
(1) \quad & \neg p \wedge q \\
(2) \quad & \neg p \implies \neg r \\
(3) \quad & \neg r \implies s \\
(4) \quad & s \implies t\\
\end{align}$$

Now we will use some Rules of Inference to deduce the conclusion from the premisses. And we do it as follows.

$$\begin{align}
& (5) \quad \neg p & \text{($(1),$ Simplification)}\\
& (6) \quad \neg p \implies s & \text{($(2),(3),$ Hypothetical & Syllogism)}\\
& (7) \quad \neg p \implies t & \text{($(6),(4),$ Hypothetical Syllogism)}\\
\therefore \quad & (8) \quad t & \text{($(7),(5),$ Modus Ponens)}\\
\end{align}$$

We have just prove that

$$\big( (\neg p \wedge q) \wedge (\neg p \implies \neg r) \wedge (\neg r \implies s) \wedge (s \implies t) \big) \implies t \quad \square$$